# How do I use CacheControl with github3.py?

Tags: python, python-requests, github3.py

From the docs of github3.py, I see that it's offering a `session` attribute, and it seems that I can do

```
g = github.GitHub(token=authentication_token)
g.session = cachecontrol.CacheControl(g.session)
```

but in fact it's `_session`, i.e. not a public API so I shouldn't use it.

Now I'm wondering how I'm supposed to inject cachecontrol?

Comment: @doelleri thanks for the edits, very much appreciated - do I upvote the edit or something?

Comment: No problem - no voting on edits or anything. You can continue to edit if you need to add information or rephrase anything; you can also rollback an edit if it isn't helpful for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade to v1.0.0a1 or v1.0.0a2 on PyPI (you'll have to use some special pip flags to install that), then you won't need to use a private API. That said, using the `_session` attribute in 0.9.x shouldn't cause adverse effects.

Comment: Yep, found that out myself. Data retrieval works but caching does not, not sure why but I'll have to investigate more.

Comment: Bug reports for that would be helpful if you figure it out

Comment: Planning to do that anyway. Looks like it's not caching the responses, for reasons unknown as of now.

Comment: @Toolforger, it's working for me. Which specific calls are you making. It seems to be caching users, repos, and other calls for me.

Comment: I'm reading users and repos, but no caching. Maybe because I'm getting different headers because I'm authenticating differently or whatever; I have been unable to find out what's going on (and CacheControl not having logging doesn't exactly help). Also, sometimes I'm getting hints that there's stuff in the cache but not found, sometimes it looks like the responses aren't getting cached in the first place; I'm likely misinterpreting something, but I have no idea what. Right now, I'm taking a look how the Ruby lib is working out, maybe I'll get results faster (not likely but anyway).

Comment: More details: For `github3.py` version `0.9`, it's enough to do `cachecontrol.CacheControl(g._session)`. No need to assign to `g._session`.